# Android R8 not keep fragment used in FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-r8

My class of fragment is removed after build because of R8, but it is used in main_activity.xml in "androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView".
On open the app release i have error of class not found

Answer (score 3):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142601969#comment12), automatically generating the proper keep rules for fragments used in `FragmentContainerView` requires you to use Android Gradle Plugin 4.1-alpha04 or higher.

Therefore you can either upgrade your Android Gradle Plugin version or add `@Keep` to manually keep your fragment.

Comment: I'm using AGP 4.2.0-alpha13 in a multi project build with navigation, but still getting the same issue. Adding @Keep annotation doesn't help either.
Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.features.home.ui.HomeFragment: make sure class name exists.

Comment: If `@Keep` isn't working, then it isn't ProGuard's fault.

Comment: I don't think so. When I disable minify, it's working. I think the issue is somewhere behind navigating across modules. Maybe the nav_graph.xml doesn't keep the class names.

Comment: You are right. Just tested again to build release with minifyEnabled = false and I'm getting the same error.  In my comment above, I meant it is working in debug build.  Whose fault is it then? Stuck on this for a week now.